# Postgesql русский unaccent расширение

Tags: postgresql, postgresql9.5, postgresql9.6

Как установить русское *unaccent* расширение для **postgresql**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

От роли postgres выполнить следующие Sql запросы:

```
CREATE EXTENSION unaccent;
CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION russian_unaccent( COPY = russian );
ALTER TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION russian_unaccent
    ALTER MAPPING FOR hword, hword_part, word
    WITH unaccent, russian_stem;
```

[Источник](https://gist.github.com/gormih/d5802750dd552f4c0975b5e89b16217c)